# OpenGL object doesn't translate to rotation axis

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm facing a problem in 2d rotations. A triangle is draw by using `opengl` drawing  primitive `GL_LINES`.

[image: Image Traingle]

Scenario is i want to rotate this triangle by using `E` and `R` key and translate this triangle along its rotation axis by pressing `up` `down` `left` `right` arrow keys.

[image: Image 2]

But now triangle is rotate but doesn't translate along it's rotate axis.For example in simple words i rotate object 90 degree angle when user press up arrow key it doesn't translate that triangle to 90 degree angle it's just translate that object simple up and down I'm stuck on this.
This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<GL\freeglut.h> 

using namespace std;    
float posX = 0.0f, posY = 0.0f, move_unit = 0.01f, angle = 0.0f;    
void init(void) {

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);    
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0);    
}

void drawFigure() {
    //LINES Make traingle
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);    
    glBegin(GL_LINES);    
    glVertex2f(0.1f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(-0.1f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.1f);
    glVertex2f(-0.1f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.1f);
    glVertex2f(0.1f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.1f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);    
    glEnd();    
}

void SpecialKeys(int key, int xpos, int ypos) {

    if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP) {    
        if (posY < 0.95f) {
            posY += move_unit;
        }
    }
    else if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN) {
        if (posY > -1.0f) {
            posY -= move_unit;
        }
    }
    else if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) {
        if (posX < 0.95f) {
            posX += move_unit;
        }

    }
    else if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) {
        if (posX > -0.95f) {
            posX = posX - move_unit;
        }
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}


void KeysFun(unsigned char key, int xpos, int ypos) {
    if (key == 'e' || key == 'E') {
        angle++;
    }
    else if (key == 'r' || key == 'R') {
        angle--;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();    
}


void display() {    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(posX, posY, 0.0f); 
    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   
    drawFigure();    
    glPopMatrix();    

    glFlush();    
}

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(450, 50);
    glutCreateWindow("C");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutSpecialFunc(&SpecialKeys);
    glutKeyboardFunc(&KeysFun);
    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: With yout current code your object rotates around the origin, right? The common order for transforms is TRS so the object rotates/scales around itself. But I don't understand what you're trying to achieve and what's wrong. Can you show a GIF?

Comment: @aslg i edit my question now you understand

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I misunderstood your code when I read it but I reproduced it on my pc.

The common order for transforms, as I said in the comments, is what you're currently doing TRS (Translation followed by Rotation followed by Scaling). This way your object will first scale around the origin, then rotate around itself and only then be translated to another point.

What I understood from your question is that you want the object to rotate around a point and then instead of moving in the screen referential (up is always up, etc) you want it to move relatively to it's new forward vector, or rotation axis. Then you have to place the rotation **before** the translation.

```
rotate( angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
translate( posX, posY, 0.0f );
```

Now the object should rotate around the origin and move relatively to the current rotation axis. In addition, if you want to rotate around another point, you can also add another translation before the rotation.

```
translate( centerX, centerY, 0.0f );
rotate( angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
translate( posX, posY, 0.0f );
```

Edit:
This reads as, translate object to point `(posX, posY)`, rotate object in axis `(0,0,1)` around center point `(centerX, centerY)`.

Edit2:
Here's how it looks if centerX and centerY are `(0,0)`, ie the origin. The triangle starts centered at `(0,0)`.

[image: Triangle motion example]

Edit3:

From the comments, you'd need to change your input. Use the transforms that you had in your original question, ie. Translation before Rotation.

```
// Let's assume we have a vector2 class that stores two floats
vector2 forward;
forward.x = sin( -_angle * DEG_TO_RADIANS );
forward.y = cos( -_angle * DEG_TO_RADIANS );

vector2 right;
right.x = forward.y;
right.y = -forward.x;

// Move one tenth of the length of the forward vector
float velocity = 0.1f;

if ( key == GLUT_KEY_UP ) {
    pos += forward * velocity;
}
else if ( key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN ) {
    pos -= forward * velocity;
}
else if ( key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT ) {
    pos += right * velocity;
}
else if ( key == GLUT_KEY_UP ) {
    pos -= right * velocity;
}
```

Of course, change the values as you see fit. Don't forget that trigonometric functions take values in radians. Also, since your object is facing upwards by default then using angle 0 `direction (0,1)` corresponds to angle 90 in conventional maths, so you have to adjust the parameters to the trignometric functions accordingly.

[image: Triangle moving like a player character]

Comment: what is `centerX` `centerY`

Comment: i'm using same order now translation happening at same rotation. But when again rotate this object from it's new position than it doesn't rotate from its origin.

Comment: @hamel123 I've uploaded a gif of the end result. Is this what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: yes but why it's rotate from center i want rotate from exact position where last time it stay

Comment: @hamel123 So basically, you want your triangle to move around. Like a 2D character from a top down game?

Comment: @hamel123 Unfortunately you cannot achieve that simply using transforms. If you were to do that you would need to store the history of rotations and translations and apply them recursively. What you need is to change how you process your input, move in a diferent direction depending on the current angle.

Comment: what software you use to make gifs and how you made this gif

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106224/discussion-between-hamel123-and-aslg).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106370/discussion-between-hamel123-and-aslg).

Comment: i try it but problem is not solve can you do this with my code rotate from exact position where last time it stay

Comment: @hamel123 I'm sorry but I won't write your code for you. I don't know what you tried and I think I've already done a lot by **giving** you the code for handling input. You only have to copy paste and change a few things to integrate in your code. If you have a problem, you're free to give details on what your problem is or ask a new question.