# Why Rotation along from center origin

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm facing a rotation problem a triangle that draw with opengl drawing primitive. I am using glut key function to rotate the triangle anticlockwise and clockwise by pressing `E` and `R` keys. And then also using glut special key function to translate the triangle x axis and y axis by pressing `up` `down` `left` `right` keys like this

[image: Rotation and Translation]

But after translate this triangle to another position than press rotation key it's not rotate form it's last position where it stay. It's rotate from center origin how to fix this.

[image: Doesn't rotate where last time stay]

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<GL\freeglut.h>

using namespace std;

float posX = 0.0f;
float posY = 0.0f;

float movethis = 0.1f;
float angle = 0.0f;


void init(void) {

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0);

}


void drawFigure() {
    glPointSize(4);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    //Total 4 liens 9 vertex
    glVertex2f(0.1f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(-0.1f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.1f);
    glVertex2f(-0.1f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.1f);
    glVertex2f(0.1f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.1f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);

    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.1f);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.0f);


    glEnd();

}

void SpecialKeys(int key, int xpos, int ypos) {

    if (key == GLUT_KEY_UP) {
            posY = posY + movethis;

        }

    else if (key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN) {
            posY = posY - movethis;
    }

    else if (key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) {
            posX = posX + movethis;
    }

    else if (key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT) {
            posX = posX - movethis;
    }


    glutPostRedisplay();
}


void KeysFun(unsigned char key, int xpos, int ypos) {
    if (key == 'e' || key == 'E') {
        angle=angle+10;
    }



    else if (key == 'r' || key == 'R') {
        angle=angle-10;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();

}


void display() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();


    glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glTranslatef(posX, posY, 0.0f);

    drawFigure();
    glFlush();

}



int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(450, 50);
    glutCreateWindow("Frame");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutSpecialFunc(&SpecialKeys);
    glutKeyboardFunc(&KeysFun);
    glutMainLoop();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I've recently answered a question I believe to be the same problem you're having: [OpenGL object doesn't translate to rotation axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35981247/opengl-object-doesnt-translate-to-rotation-axis/35984197#35984197) (Also, read the comments for context on edits)

Comment: @aslg i see that answer but that's not clearly answer

Comment: You need to place the rotation _after_ the translation.

Comment: See [this Game Dev StackExchage post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16719/what-is-the-correct-order-to-multiply-scale-rotation-and-translation-matrices-f)

Comment: @aslg when i place the rotation after the translation than it's just doing the triangle up or down left right

Comment: Same thing I answered in the question I linked. Unfortunately you cannot simply rely on transforms in order to move your triangle like a game character. You must calculate the forward vector and use it to move the triangle.

Comment: @aslg can you show me how to add vector and calculate it just in simple words

Comment: If you're serious about using a low-level graphics API like OpenGL, it would be to your benefit to learn about the mathematics of matrix transformations. In particular: all basic transform matrices operate about the origin, but you can multiply matrices to create more complex transformations.

Comment: @MannDeep I see. You're the same person from that question, just under a different account. I still think my answer is fairly explicit. You should google about vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the order of operations in the matrix multiplication chain "backwards". You first have to rotate, then translate, but if you write it as

```
rotate
translate
vertices
```

data is traveling "upwards", so the vertices "see" first the translation, then the rotation. Solution: Flip the order of rotation and translation.